# Column Width not working in EE3 Grid field when editing entry

Tags: grid, ee3

Has anyone worked out how to get the Grid field in EE3 to follow the 'column width' parameters?  I have a Grid 'row' that has a WYSIWYG field and I can't work out how to keep it from collapsing down - see attached image.  Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: See https://expressionengine.com/support/bugs/21340 for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "column width" parameters does not seems to be used for now.. What i did is  modify themes/ee/cp/css/common.min.css
Because my screeen is 1920px wide.. i change the max-width of .col-group to 1500px.. at least i see more!.. 
AND
i commented the `.grid-input-form th {/* min-width:220px*/}` 
Hope it will help!

Comment: Thanks for your input - we ended up hacking the CP CSS too, but it's far from ideal.  Guess it's the best we got for now :(

Comment: This has been fixed now in 3.5.7: https://twitter.com/EllisLab/status/865281110665830400

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason the option to set columns widths is not observed. I recall EL claiming it was necessary for the CP to be responsive in ee3. I find that ridiculous as it is easy enough to implement a mobile and desktop view with min/max widths, media queries and maybe a little JS. We all do it everywhere, all the time.